# What does this line mean in verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga, lcd, intel-fpga

From http://www.johnloomis.org/digitallab/lcdlab/lcdlab3/lcdlab3.qdoc.html

How can I change DATA_BUS so that it is not using inout.

```
// BIDIRECTIONAL TRI STATE LCD DATA BUS

assign DATA_BUS = (LCD_RW_INT? 8'bZZZZZZZZ: DATA_BUS_VALUE)
```

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer your second question. Can you provide more information on how DATA_BUS is being used? A continuous assign can be done on a wire as well.

Comment: From this website is where the line is from. Used in code to display on LCD screen.
http://www.johnloomis.org/digitallab/lcdlab/lcdlab3/lcdlab3.qdoc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a continuous assign statement to DATA_BUS using a ternary operator.

```
assign DATA_BUS = (LCD_RW_INT? 8'bZZZZZZZZ: DATA_BUS_VALUE)
```

The ternary operator could be thought of as a mini if-else statement. In english it could be translated like so assuming LCD_RW_INT is a 1 bit flag:

```
if LCD_RW_INT == 1'b1: 
    DATA_BUS = 8'bZZZZZZZZ 
else: 
    DATA_BUS = DATA_BUS_VALUE
```

Comment: What does True stand for?

Comment: Edited to reflect truth value for LCD_RW_INT. LCD_RW_INT is False when all of its bits are 0's.

Comment: After looking at the source you provided LCD_RW_INT is a flag of one bit, so 1'b1 would be true and 1'b0 would be false.

Comment: Perfect thanks. But I am getting an error using your code. Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at LCD_Display.v(72) near text: "begin";  expecting "endmodule".

Comment: What code? I did not provide you verilog code. I clearly stated "In english it could be translated like so." I explained what the ternary operator did, but I did not provide you equivalent code.

Comment: Can I not use this to work? 

if (LCD_RW_INT == 1'b1) 
    DATA_BUS = 8'bZZZZZZZZ ;
else
    DATA_BUS = DATA_BUS_VALUE;

Comment: Definitely not! That is nowhere near valid Verilog. The Ternary operator is the correct operator to use for a continuous conditional assign statement. Why are you trying to change it?

Comment: I had to change the DATA_BUS from inout to wire or something to use between modules. And when I did that the assign gave an error.


Edit: This error: Error (10231): Verilog HDL error at LCD_Display.v(71): value cannot be assigned to input "DATA_BUS"

Comment: Please update your question with errors you are getting. Your question primarily asked what the Ternary operator did, not anything about an error you were getting. Please ask a new question as this was marked as duplicate.

Comment: Or it gives this error if DATA_BUS is changed to wire: Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at lcdlab3.v(15) near text: "wire";  expecting a direction.

Comment: @EdwardElric inout can't just be changed to wire. You could change inout to output if you just want output. If you just want input you can change it to input, but then you can't assign anything to it like above.

Comment: How can I assign and have an output?

Comment: I think you need to ask a new question or go look up how Verilog handles ports.